# modulo of a large number

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic

I need help with solving modulo of large numbers, wondering if it is possible to compute the answer without the use of calculator.

for example: 545^112 (mod 23) how can this be solved? 
I reduced my answer to 545^2 (mod 23) and wonder if there is a way to continue without the use of calculator to compute 545^2.

and how can I find 545^112 (mod 24) from here?

Thanks.

Comment: note that $545^2\equiv 1 \mod 24$

Comment: Is it a typo or on purpose that you use once $23$ and once $24$?

Answer (score 1):

A simple reduction is to note that if 
$$a \equiv b \pmod{n} $$
then 
$$a^c \equiv b^c \pmod{n} $$
So you can reduce $545$ modulo $23$.

In combination with the reduction you used already, this results in something very manageable.

Answer (score 0):

You can reduce $545 \pmod{23}$.  So $545^{112}\equiv 545^2\equiv 16^2 \pmod{23}$.

For your second question, you can reduce $545 \pmod{24}$ and you can reduce $112 \pmod{8}$ since $\varphi(24)=8$